# Is this question about chinese exchanges on-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/340/are-there-any-measurable-indicators-of-chinese-exchanges-accepting-ethereum

This does relate to ethereum, but I'm not sure whether we want it (and similar questions) on the site. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

It's been deleted, but I would generally say "No" as it's a question that would quickly become outdated/irrelevant. It's more like chit-chat than a FAQ.

If instead it was a question about "What exchanges can Ether be traded on" and the answer listed exchange names, their url's and even geographical location... then I'd say that's a much more useful question/answer.

I'd further recommend it be a community wiki to encourage ongoing updates as exchanges come and go...